# phantomjs and requirejs

Tags: requirejs, phantomjs

codes in file main.js is like this:

```
      phantom.injectJs("libs/require-1.0.7.js");
      require.config(
        {
          baseUrl: "" 
        }
      );
      require([], function(){});
```

when i run "phantomjs main.js" in the commandline, requirejs doesn't work well in the main.js. I know how to use requirejs in the page running in the browser(including phantomjs' way: page.open(url, callback)), but not like above. I tries using requirejs like the main.js, it is a popular problem, i think. Thank you!

Comment: I got a little further ... you can get access to the actual requirejs require variable like this:
require = null;
phantom.injectJs('target/dependencies/requirejs-tar.gz/require.js');

Comment: @Thomas, i will try your way, :)

Comment: I gave up on getting this working nicely and instead used the method in http://tech-gym.com/2011/11/javascript/572.html (Japanese) which is on github here: https://github.com/azu/AMDTesting and which comes from sample code in https://github.com/rpflorence/non-trivial-js ... I also generate the HTML page on the fly to avoid having to hardcode the tests I want to run which adds another layer of madness.  If you get anything simpler working I would love to hear about it!

Comment: I was a little unsure if this is the same as my question so I made a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187669/how-do-i-reliably-execute-jasmine-tests-that-utilize-requirejs-via-phantomjs

Comment: I am dying to find a solution for this problem!

Comment: Full code with the error would help. Not sure whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156190/exposing-variables-from-phantomjs-call-to-injectjs) is your situation.

Answer (score 3):

I just struggled for some time.  My solution is not clean, but it works, and I'm happy with that due to the unfinished api documentation from phantomjs.

## Wordy explanation

You need three files.  One is your amd phantomjs test file which I'll call "amd.js".  The second is your html page to load which I'll name "amd.html".  Finally the browser test which I called "amdTestModule.js".

In amd.html, declare your script tag per normal:

```
<script data-main="amdTestModule.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

In your phantomjs test file, this is where it gets hacky.  Create your page, and load in the 'fs' module.  This allows you to open a relative file path.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open('file://' + fs.absolute('tests/amd.html'));
```

Now since requirejs loads files asynchronously, we can't just pass in a callback into page.open and expect things to go smoothly.  We need some way to either
1) Test our module in the browser and communicate the result back to our phantomjs context.  Or
2) Tell our phantomjs context that upon loading all the resources, to run a test.

#1 was simpler for my case.  I accomplished this via:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    msg = msg.split('=');
    if (msg[1] === 'success') {
        console.log('amd test successful');
    } else {
        console.log('amd test failed');
    }
    phantom.exit();
};
```

**See full code below for my console.log message.

Now phantomjs apparently has an event api built in but it is undocumented.   I was also successfully able to get request/response messages from their page.onResourceReceived and page.onResourceRequested - meaning you can debug when all your required modules are loaded.  To communicate my test result however, I just used console.log.

Now what happens if the console.log message is never ran?  The only way I could think of resolving this was to use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('amd test failed - timeout');
    phantom.exit();
}, 500);
```

That should do it!

## Full Code

**directory structure**

```
/projectRoot  
  /tests  
    - amd.js  
    - amdTestModule.js  
    - amd.html  
    - require.js (which I symlinked)  
    - <dependencies> (also symlinked)
```

**amd.js**

```
'use strict';
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

/*
page.onResourceRequested = function(req) {
    console.log('\n');
    console.log('REQUEST');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req, null, 4));
    console.log('\n');
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    console.log('\n');
    console.log('RESPONSE');
    console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    console.log('\n');
};
*/

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    msg = msg.split('=');
    if (msg[1] === 'success') {
        console.log('amd test successful');
    } else {
        console.log('amd test failed');
    }
    phantom.exit();
};

page.open('file://' + fs.absolute('tests/amd.html'));

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('amd test failed - timeout');
    phantom.exit();
}, 500);
```

**amd.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script data-main='amdTestModule.js' src='require.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**amdTestModule.js**

```
require([<dependencies>], function(<dependencies>) {
    ...
    console.log(
        (<test>) ? "test=success" : "test=failed"
    );
});
```

**console**

```
$ phantomjs tests/amd.js
amd test successful
```

Answer (score 1):

you are misunderstanding webpage.injectJs()

it's for injecting scripts into the page you are loading, not into the phantomjs runtime environment.

So using .injectJs() is making requirejs load up into your page, not into phantomjs.exe.

That said, phantomjs's runtime environment has an aproximation of commonjs.  RequireJs will not run on there by default.  If you felt especially (VERY) motivated, you could attempt porting the require-shim made for nodejs, but it doesn't work out of the box, and would require an incredibly deep understanding of the runtimes.   for more details: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

**a better idea:**
probably you should make sure you have commonjs versions of your javascript you wish to run.  i personally write my code in typescript so i can build for either commonjs or amd.  i use commonjs for phantomjs code,  and amd for nodejs and browser.