# How do I reliably execute Jasmine tests that utilize requirejs via phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to run jasmine test. My jasmine tests are using require around the describe blocks to ensure all the right modules are loaded.

My tests would not run because `page.evaluate -> jasmine.getEnv().execute();` runs BEFORE requirejs finishes loading the modules.

I was wondering if anyone knows a real good way around this. I have an answer I'm going to post below but would love to compare notes via other answers. If yours is better, I will def pick it as answer obviously :)

Comment: I don't now if I should be happy that no one commented and I had a good answer or to be sad no one had a better alternate. Accepted my answer and hope it will be useful to someone someday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution, with jQuery available, is this:

Load a config file before any of your tests run.

```
var jasmine_deferreds = [];

// Setup an event to fire on the document
// I actually did this with native code rather than jquery because
// I wanted to minimize jquery usage

// ....

// setTimeout so all files loaded after this will finish registering their requires
setTimeout( function() {

  $.when.apply( null, jasmine_deferreds ).then( function() {

    // Fire event that was created

  });

}, 5 );
```

It's up to you how you want to build up the array of deferreds and then resolve them. I essentially pushed to the array and then resolved when the require was done. I wrapped require with my own version that would know to resolve it upon completion automatically - so I don't need to push and resolve manually in each test.

Then in my phantom file I do this:

```
page.evaluate ->
    mylistener = ( document ) -> jasmine.getEnv().execute();
    document.addEventListener( 'test_ready_event', mylistener, false);
```

This makes it so I know all my require modules are loaded without having some arbitrary `setTimeout` that could be too short once I am loading too many files. The one `setTimeout` I'm using is safe because it's only being used to fire after main callstack is done. It doesn't really care about the time.

Answer (score 3):

I did something a little different -- my HTML page has a function, wrapped in a require() call:

```
var run_tests = function (specfiles) {
    require(specfiles, function () {
        jasmine.getEnv().execute();
    });
};
```

Then I `page.evaluate( function (test_specs) { run_tests(test_specs) }, ['test1.spec', 'test2.spec']);`

Comment: That's a good answer for most people I think. The problem is if you have a huge app you have now defined all possible modules in a real big list that you have to maintain rather than the modules maintaining themselves.

Comment: Actually, I am using a filesystem walker to discover the test modules.  I'm not clear how tests can discover themselves. You have to have the list somewhere, don't you? Then you can make require do the work. It's already managing when the code can execute.

I can totally believe that I'm missing your point, which is why I bothered to reply. :)

Comment: Thanks for response - would have got back sooner but I was out of country. I'll have to look into the walker idea. Right now I have a list of the "top" modules which then include all the ones below rather than using a walker. So the walker is providing the info that gets passed in as "specfiles" then?

Comment: Only about a half-year later, right? But yes, the walker was set up to run under PhantomJS, and it used the fs module to walk the tree and seek out test files. The test runner is kind of lengthy (~200 lines) and full of enough embarrassing hacks that it's not been made public, but it's similar to existing solutions -- its main reason for existence was to generate an xunit-style report for use in Jenkins -- existing solutions didn't do that.