# Protractor promise not resolving on declaration

Tags: protractor

When I execute the statements without using promises, it just returns a promise.

Like the following does not work:

```
devices = element.all(devicesRepeater)
expect(devices.length).toEqual factories.devices.length
```

But promise style works:

```
element.all(devicesRepeater).then (devices)->
  expect(devices.length).toEqual factories.devices.length
```

But its shown in the protractor API that it should resolve e.g.: 
http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.

`// Returns a promise that resolves to an array var 
rows = element.all(by.repeater('cat in pets'))`

Same is true for waiting and all. Like in the following question, waiting blocks and then the expect call works:

[How can I wait for a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072327/how-can-i-wait-for-a-condition#answer-22103831)

Whereas in my project, I have to put all the logic inside the promise callback block.

Should I write a then block for each of them or is there a way to block until promise resolves.

Comment: Hope this gets some attention, I'm having issues with promises not resolving as well, even if I have use `expect()` with them.

Comment: length is not a property of ElementArrayFinder.  Use count() instead:

`devices = element.all(devicesRepeater)
expect(devices.count()).toEqual factories.devices.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

length is not a property of ElementArrayFinder. Use count() instead:

`devices = element.all(devicesRepeater) 
expect(devices.count()).toEqual factories.devices.length`

Comment: Yes I have been using count since then. But thanks for adding it here so that others can find the answer